# embedded button.swf does not fire CLICK event

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

i'm trying to embed a swf to my as3 flex project like this:

```
[Embed(source = "../assets/next_button.swf")]
[Bindable]
protected var nextButtonClass:Class;
protected var next_btn:MovieClip = next_btn = new nextButtonClass() as MovieClip;
// ...
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAdChange);
```

next_button.swf is as2 and created with adobe flash cs4. there is a single button inside it.

if i change type of button symbol to movieclip at next_button.fla, there is no problem at passing CLICK event.

i tried to cast next_btn to mx.controls.Button and fl.controls.Button classes, next_btn is becoming null in that case.

by the way button is reacting mouseover and click events properly just doesn't pass it to upper swf.

is there any trick i can do to pass Button events to my container swf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try embedding and instancing the symbol from inside the swf, not the entire swf:

```
 [Embed(source = "../assets/next_button.swf", symbol"MyButton")]
```

You will obviously need to replace `MyButton` with the actual symbol name of the button.

That should give you more direct access to it, since it won't be wrapped by a `Loader`.

Comment: i gave button name 'next_btn' and changed code so:
    [Embed(source = "../assets/next_button_as3.swf", symbol = "next_btn")]

i got these errors:

Error: definition for symbol 'next_btn' not found
Error: Unable to transcode ../assets/next_button.swf.

but i got same errors when i tried it with next_button_as3.swf, am i doing something wrong?

i can trace this.next_btn inside both swfs, outputs are so:

as2 => _level0.next_btn
as3 => [object next_button]

Comment: you need to set a "linkage id", not an instance name. http://www.jessewarden.com/archives/flex/preloader/flash_preloader_03.gif

Comment: thanks, i tried so, no error at compile time. but "var next_btn:MovieClip = new nextButtonClass() as MovieClip;" code assigns null value to next_btn variable this time. how can a "new" operator return null value?

Comment: if the cast to `MovieClip` fails it'll be null, try assigning it to a `Sprite` instead

Comment: and that's the solution! but Sprite didn't work, used DisplayObject instead.

Answer (score 1):

to summarize, after the solution grapefrukt suggested, code looks like this:

```
[Embed(source = "../assets/next_button.swf", symbol="next_button")]
[Bindable]
protected var nextButtonClass:Class;
protected var next_btn:DisplayObject = new nextButtonClass() as DisplayObject;
// ...
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAdChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for an As3 script to access properties of an AS2 SWF. If you have access to the fla, why not change the button fla into an AS3 project?

Comment: actually i have to write both as2 and as3 version of the same project. i wanted to be able to use same assets for both project.

and assets will be prepared by a designer group, we may not have a cs4 under our hand to change flas.

and as you say there is no problem if assets are as3, and i'm afraid there is no solution for as2 buttons.

Comment: is there any way you could totally separate the logic from the design.  that would seem the way forward if you have a designer group preparing the assets. this way you would be able to work both as2 & as3.

it seems actually that the real issue here is the lack of separation between design & logic.

Comment: that's how we seperate it :) our designer team has no idea about flex, mxml etc. they're binary guys.